# Dual monitor setup on a laptop: internal monitor peeking through on external display

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, multi-monitor, laptop

Recently I began to use my laptop (Dell Inspiron N5020) with an external display. I use the displays side-by-side, internal on the left, external on the right.

The problem is, however, that the display on the external monitor seems to be shifted to the right by a few pixels, and at the same time a few pixel wide column from the right edge of the internal display is duplicated on the left edge of the external. On a screenshot this is not visible. I illustrated what I'm actually talking about on this image: [image: Illustration of the problem]

The type of the external monitor doesn't seem to matter. Same thing with a Medion 1680x1050 monitor with VGA connector, and a Dell U2311H through HDMI. Also I tried to set various resolution combinations, and it seems to only happen when the internal monitor is at its native resolution (which is 1366x768)

(I have Linux Mint 15 x64 with Cinnamon.)

Comment: You should check the output of `xrandr` to ensure that the two displays are not overlapping in their layout. They probably aren't, but it's worth checking, especially if your mouse is really showing on two monitors the way you depict it. You can easily rearrange the windows using the GUI-based `arandr` or using `xrandr` command-line options.

(Another possibility is that perhaps you're just seeing the window decorations crossing over. I've experienced this in several WMs.)

Comment: I use arandr and xrandr, the displays definitely aren't overlapping. Also I found a workaround: I saved the setup script with arandr, then shifted the right display by two pixels to the right, so that logically there is a two pixel wide gap between them. Visually it's totally fine. If I take a screenshot, the gap is filled with random garbled pixels, which aren't visible physically. Drawback however: the mouse is not stopped at the inner edges of the screens. So I can't place auto hiding panels to the top of the internal display, or the bottom of the external one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem, but found a different solution that does not have the drawbacks of your proposed solution. It turned out that there was a 2 pixel wide unused column on the left side of my arrangement, so instead of shifting the right display to the right, I shifted the left display (internal) to the left, covering that unused column. Everything is fine now. Here is how my scripts looks like:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output LVDS --mode 1366x768 --pos -2x312 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1366x0 --rotate normal
```

Observe the -2 on the first

```
--pos
```

argument.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. But it seems the mouse still doesn't stop at the inner edges - at least this is the case in XFCE.

Comment: I see what you mean. In my case I only get that in one of the borders, in which I don't need it to stop. Let's keep waiting for a better solution then.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure the desktop layout? If you used the GUI tool to do so, check to see if you have accidentally positioned the 2 screens overlapping slightly.